# How many Redis connections are used with Actioncable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, actioncable

I'm looking at moving my app's deployment to Heroku, and I'd like to determine if it can correctly run there on the basic plan before putting in the effort to migrate. The basic plan limits Redis to 20 connections.

I don't fundamentally understand the Rails/Redis connection architecture. Is there a single connection to Actioncable, which is then distributing the data, or is the connection per actual client (i.e. one connection for every browser tab)?

Comment: Good question. Not enough covered yet across the web as I struuggle to identify the purpose of some Redis connections which are flagged "Actioncable"

Comment: @Maxence, Actioncable is Rails' websocket implementation and (typically?) uses redis as the way of distributing the real-time data as I understand it.

Comment: Hi @ElTea Well I was wondering how many clients were used for multiple AC connections. Actually I saw a few different Actioncable connections in Redis after I named them all (Sidekiq, Rails app Redis; ActionCable ..). I was wondering how many clients could be created. This thread https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/hz14wg/would_someone_be_able_to_explain_redis/ and Mathhew Oriordan answer clearly states Actioncable is multiplexing across only 2 redis connections. I have then flushed my Redis DB and this seems accurate. I will monitor again to see if more than 2 Redis clients are created

Comment: Also I have namespaced Redis by using multiple Redis DBs. So I guess some AC connections that I saw belonged to different applications I was running as development on my machine. Now I have made everything clean I hope my ap will stick to 2 clients for AC. It is no problem when serving locally or from a Bare metal machine but on Heroku only 20 connections are avaailable or have to fork large amount of money for extra redis clients.

Answer (score 1):

As [per the docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#server-side-components-connections),

> An individual user will create one consumer-connection pair per browser tab, window, or device they have open.

ActionCable lets you identify a connection using a connection identifier, typically a global object called current_user in most cases. With this approach, you can later retrieve all open connections by a given user (and potentially disconnect them all if the user is deleted or unauthorized or have too many connections open).

Also, note that ActionCable uses a worker pool to run connection callbacks and channel actions in isolation from your server's main thread.

Comment: Hi @theterminalguy At the moment, in development, `redis-cli` `CLIENT LIST` returns 10 Redis connections for Actioncable. Although I have a single user connected. But the user ID has changed. Is there a chance 8 of these connections depend on user which have been deleted days or weeks ago ? Or is it normal to have a log of Redis connections not linked to the number of Users connected ? Thanks

Comment: Ok after killing Puma and restarting it. Only 2 Redis connections are used if I log to the app with the user. All 10 connections have been killed. Yet I am not too sure why 10 connections happened to be created as I have played with a single user today...

Comment: Are you using Sidekiq? `CLIENT LIST` should show you the names of all connected clients for ActionCable it is ActionCable-PID-the-process-id, for Sidekiq, one way you could tell is with the cmd=brpop field.

Comment: I use Sidekick indeed. But sidekiq clients are properly named. No confusion. But also I broadcast from inside sidekiq workers to Action cable channels. Then I was thinking Sidekiq could create Actioncable clients. But I changed Sidekiq concurrency from 5 to 1, then to 10. And I still have around 3 Actioncable redis clients after I restarted Puma and flushed all redis keys. I am not too sure why these 10 AC clients today. I will monitor again tomorrow... tks for your comeback in this

Comment: Hi @theterminalguy. I appreciate the link, but the one consumer-connection pair seems to be referring to the application server. From 3.1: "The connection itself does not deal with any specific application logic beyond authentication and authorization."
That sounds to me like it's in the Rails application server, not in redis. So I'm still not sure if there's a 1-to-1 between application connections and what redis considers connections. (I admit I'm poking at this with a stick in the dark).